# Loading external javascript after click

Tags: javascript, html, url, external

I have an external script (social media chat) which is actively used by site visitors, but slows down my website for 5-7 sec. on 3G connection, which is a problem.

I wonder if there is a way not to load the script at all before user clicks some link, for example, I could make fixed block at the side of the page.

The html integration code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?150"></script>
<div id="vk_community_messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 136838443, {disableExpandChatSound: "1",tooltipButtonText: "Got a question? We're here to help!"});
</script>
```

I'd like to have something like

```
<a href='javascript: external code'>Got a question? We're here to help!"</a>
```

and I didn't find out if it's possible.

I'm a beginner so I apologize if my question is stupid. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I guess you could always attach an event listener to the anchor tag of `mouseover` and then append the script to the page but then you will want to add an `ID` to that script tag so you don't append duplicates each time the mouse hovers the link. I think that would be the only logical way of knowing when the client is about to click that link.

Comment: If you defer initializing that community messages widget until a click, wouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: @zbnrg you mean "until a click" on any part of the document/page or on the link?

Comment: @zbnrg, the widget itself is deferred but the upper part (with the link to src) doesn't work correctly with "defer" tag. So it takes all it's seconds to load.  And is there a way to specifically defer  _until a click_?